# PDO:sqlite doesnt INSERT data, yet no error

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

```
try
{
    $res = $db->exec($sql);
    if ($res === FALSE)
    {
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
        die();
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die($e->getCode().':'.$e->getMessage());
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die($e->getCode().':'.$e->getMessage());
}
```

No error info, and neither does it get caught as an exception. Yet $res is FALSE and no data gets inserted.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

But when I echo `$sql` and enter that query in SQLiteManager, it works inserting the data.

Comment: please insert code into code sample block

Comment: Can you give us an example query (and maybe the table structure)? Which version of php do you us? Which version of the sqlite library does this version of php use (phpinfo() can tell)?

Comment: Refer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517887/how-to-show-sql-errors-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

I used sqlite only with Python, but I had to commit insert/update statements there... Maybe that's the case here too? http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php

Comment: Thats only when using transaction.
0:There is no active transaction
Im using exec which should commit execute immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the directory where you store file is writable.

Comment: If applicable, also ensure that SELinux is in "permissive" mode.