# How to show SQL errors in SQLite?

Tags: php, sqlite, iis, pdo

Using SQLite in PHP (thus using PDO), I have this code:

```
try {
$db = new PDO("sqlite:C:\Program Files\Spiceworks\db\spiceworks_prod.db");

echo "Done.<br /><b>";

$query = "SELECT id FROM Devices LIMIT 5";

echo "Results: ";

$result = $db->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    print_r($row)."|";
}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

But that does not print out any data from the SQL. I know the database has data in it and the connection is valid. If I change the query to say:

```
$query = "SELECT BLAHid FROM FakeDevices LIMIT 5";
```

Nothing changes. Nothing from SQL gets printed out again, and I see no errors even though this is clearly an invalid SQL query.

In both situations,  the "Done" and "Results" gets printed out okay. How can I print out SQL errors, like if the query is invalid?

Comment: Check error_reporting in your php files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell PDO to throw exceptions. You can do that by adding the following line after you connect to the database:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:C:\Program Files\Spiceworks\db\spiceworks_prod.db");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

That way you can catch all exceptions except for a possible problem with the first line, the database connection itself.